# How to calculate $\int_0^1 \frac{t dt}{\sqrt{(t-x)^2+y^2+z^2}}$?

Tags: calculus, integration

How to calculate 
$$\int_0^1 \frac{t \, \mathrm{d}t}{\sqrt{(t-x)^2+y^2+z^2}}$$
Here, $x,y,z$ are fixed.

Answer (score 2):

Let $u=t-x$, we get
$$I=\int \frac{t }{\sqrt{(t-x)^2+y^2+z^2}}\, \mathrm{d}t=\int \frac{u+x}{\sqrt{u^{2}+y^{2}+z^{2}}}\, \mathrm{d}u$$
then let $u=\sqrt{y^{2}+z^{2}}\tan m$
\begin{align*}
I&=\int \sec m\left ( \sqrt{y^{2}+z^{2}}\tan m+x \right )\, \mathrm{d}m\\
&=\sqrt{y^{2}+z^{2}}\int \tan m\sec m\, \mathrm{d}m+x\int \sec m\, \mathrm{d}m\\
&=\sqrt{y^{2}+z^{2}}\sec m+x\ln\left | \tan m+\sec m \right |+C
\end{align*}
Hope you can take it from here.